# How do I enable checkin for my page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a client who owns a small retail store and has a Facebook page. When someone at the location checks in to the place, it creates a new page. I click on "know the owner" and send out the invite email and Facebook gives a prompt for editing the page. It also says that you will be able to combine the pages in the "next step"—I finish all the steps and there is no option where I can combine the pages and it creates a new page every time.

Any idea how to combine the pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Go to the page
- Get into the edit screens
- Update Basic Information
- Update the address

Make sure the page category is set to Local Businesses & Places otherwise the above won't work.

As far as the address information goes; Facebook gives the disclaimer:

> Note: If you add a valid address, users will be able to see and check in to your page using Facebook Places. It may take a few hours for our system to process the address.

Make sure to wait a few hours (I'd bet on just wait until the next day) to see that your business is on Places.

For the second part of your question, I have not ever been able to combine pages successfully (I manage a six location restaurant chain's digital presence) so I always just take control and try to direct the visitors via links to the official page.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I tried to find the address and I could never find, but your this "page category is set to Local Businesses & Places otherwise the above won't work." was important, which I failed to do earlier.

Comment: I had one more question. How do I enable checkin deals for my page now ?

Comment: Check ins are enabled with the local pages setting and a valid address